# making a GET request inside a NodeJs app using express

Tags: node.js, http, express

I have the following code in my server.js:

```
var fileSystemPath = path.join(__dirname, '../variable/public');
app.use('/VC', express.static(quickstartPath));
```

AND

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
response.redirect('/VC/?roomname=' + request.query.roomname + '&username=' + request.query.username);
});
```

While the parameters are formatted into the URL, it is treated as a redirect and not a GET request. How can I get these parameter values in my /VC/ branch.
Note I have been unable to use http.get because the path is definedby the express app

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do a bit better? You are doing a response.redirect, which is why you are seeing the redirect. Do you just wnat to serve content on app.get('/',...) using the VC path?

Comment: I want someone arriving at  mywebsite.com?roomname=1&username=abc to be sent to mywebsite.com/VC?roomname=1&username=abc and then for the page there to read this as a GET request with roomname and username as parameters

Comment: If you want the user to be 'sent' to another address - you should use a redirect, like the one that you've provided. The user's request would still be a GET request, but your response would be a Redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just used

```
tmp = [];
location.search
    .substr(1)
    .split("&")
    .forEach(function (item) {
      tmp = item.split("=");
      if (tmp[0] === 'username') username = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
      if (tmp[0] === 'roomname') roomname = decodeURIComponent(tmp[1]);
    });
```

at the /vs part

Answer (score 0):

You are expected to see a redirect because you're doing a  `response.redirect`

If I understood correctly, you want to serve static content on that particular request to the `'/'` endpoint with those parameters. In that case what you're looking for is probably pipe.

You can do something like this:

```
app.get('/', function(request, response) {
  // construct your servers static URL using the host header.
  let resource = request.headers.host + '/VC/?roomname=' + request.query.roomname + '&username=' + request.query.username;
  // Make a get request.
  http.get(resource, (getResponse) => {
    // Pipe the response.
    return res.pipe(getResponse);
  });
});
```